# How to translate switch statement to Perl

Tags: perl, csh

I am porting a csh script to Perl. I am  doing a switch statement in Perl. I am not sure if this is right, based on the different comments that switch statements are no longer in use in Perl. Can you please give me an idea if this is right?
Also in switch statement do we use 'when' or 'case'?

This is the csh code:

```
set machine = c16991
set pgMachine = lc0140


if ( ! -e /abc/site/home/$USER/.userauthentication) then
echo "-F- .userauthentication file must be created in /abc/site/home/$USER "
echo "-I- .userauthentication file format: <emailaddress> <unix pwd>. 
echo "-I- Please make sure /abc/site/home/$USER/.userauthentication  permission is set to 000"
exit
endif

set permissionCheck = `ls -ltra /abc/site/home/$USER/.userauthentication |  awk '{print $1}' | 
if ($permissionCheck != 'DASHrwDASHDASHDASHDASHDASHDASHDASH') then
echo "-F- /abc/site/home/$USER/.userauthentication permission is set to    $permission1"
exit
endif


@ i = 1

while ($i <= $#argv) 
   switch ($argv[$i])
   case -block:
     shift
     set DBB1 = $argv[$i]
     shift
     breaksw
   case -tag:
     shift
     set tag = $argv[$i]
     shift 
     breaksw
   case -local:
  shift
     set local = $argv[$i]
     shift
     breaksw
   case -ar:
     shift
     set arType = $argv[$i]
     shift
     breaksw  

   default:
     echo "-E- Invalid switch -> {$argv[$i]} found!"
     goto usage
    exit
   endsw
end



if ($local == 'y') then
   if ($tag == "")then
   echo "-F- Please enter tag value to proceed!"
   exit
   endif
endif


set DBB1 = $DBB

### grab data locally

set shipLogFile = "$WARD/ship/log/${DBB1}.ship.log"
set shipUsername = `grep "Username:" $shipLogFile | sed 's/.*Username: //' |    sed 's/;.*//'`
set reviewCloseFile = "$WARD/ship/ip/${DBB1}/swizzled/review/${DBB1}.close"
set accept10SumFile = "$WARD/ship/ip/${DBB1}/swizzled/pds/logs/${DBB1}.ccdo_accept10.iss.log.sum"
set shipDate = `zgrep "::RUNTIME:: SHIP end time/date:" $shipLogFile | sed 's/.*time\/date\://g' | sed 's#"##g'`

else


 ###grab data from archive [DEFAULT]

if ($shipTag == "") then
if ($DBB1 == "") then
# grab DEFAULT hip value from running WARD, $DBB
set DBB1 = $DBB
endif
# grab DEFAULT ship tag value for archive from the latest tag
set shipTag = `ls -t $PROJ_ARCHIVE/noa/${DBB1}/ip_handoff_noa | grep  "^$STEPPING" | grep RTL | grep -v RTL0 | grep -v "_TEMP" | head -n 1`
else
if ($DBB1 == "") then
# grab DEFAULT hip value from running WARD, $DBB
set DBB1 = $DBB
endif
endif

set shipUsername = `zgrep "User Name:"    $PROJ_ARCHIVE/noa/${DBB1}/ip_handoff_noa/$shipTag/${DBB1}.ip_handoff_noa.manifes t.gz | sed 's/.*\.//g' | sed 's/^ \+\| \+$//g'`
set shipLogFile =  "$PROJ_ARCHIVE/noa/${DBB1}/ship_noa/${shipTag}/ship/log/${DBB1}.ship.log"
set reviewCloseFile =   "$PROJ_ARCHIVE/noa/${DBB1}/iphandoff_review_noa/${shipTag}/review/${DBB1}.close. gz"
set accept10SumFile =    "$PROJ_ARCHIVE/noa/${DBB1}/ipqa_noa/${shipTag}/pds/logs/${DBB1}.ccdo_accept10.is s.log.sum.gz"
set shipDate = `zgrep "Current Date:"  $PROJ_ARCHIVE/noa/${DBB1}/ship_noa/${shipTag}/${DBB1}.ship_noa.manifest.gz | sed 's/.*\. //g'`

 endif






 ### create /tmp/transpose_$$.pl script

 touch /tmp/transpose_$$.pl; rm /tmp/transpose_$$.pl

 echo '#\!/usr/intel/pkgs/perl/5.8.5/bin/perl -w' >> /tmp/transpose_$$.pl
 echo 'use strict;' >> /tmp/transpose_$$.pl
 echo 'use English;' >> /tmp/transpose_$$.pl
 echo '(our $PROG_NAME = $0) =~ s#^.*/##;' >> /tmp/transpose_$$.pl
 echo 'my $file = shift;' >> /tmp/transpose_$$.pl
 echo 'open (FILE, $file) or die "***E: Error opening $file for reading: $!\n";' >> /tmp/transpose_$$.pl
 echo 'my @lines;' >> /tmp/transpose_$$.pl
 echo 'while (<FILE>){' >> /tmp/transpose_$$.pl
 echo '    chomp $_;' >> /tmp/transpose_$$.pl
 echo '    push (@lines, $_);' >> /tmp/transpose_$$.pl
 echo '}' >> /tmp/transpose_$$.pl
 echo 'print "@lines";' >> /tmp/transpose_$$.pl
 echo 'print "\n";' >> /tmp/transpose_$$.pl
 echo '1;' >> /tmp/transpose_$$.pl
 chmod 740 /tmp/transpose_$$.pl
```

This is the Perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

 use strict;
 use warnings;

 use Data::Dumper; ##print Dumper()
 use feature qw(switch);

  my $machine = c16991;
  my $pgMachine =lc0140;


  if ( ! -e /abc/site/home/$USER/.userauthentication) 
  system (echo "-F- .userauthentication file must be created in  /abc/site/home/$USER" )
  system (echo "-I- .userauthentication file format: <emailaddress> <unix pwd>.")
  system (echo "-I- Please make sure /abc/site/home/$USER/.userauthentication permission is set to 000")
  exit
  endif

  my $permissionCheck = `ls -ltra /nfs/site/home/$USER/.userauthentication | awk '{print $1}' 
    if ($permissionCheck != 'DASHrwDASHDASHDASHDASHDASHDASHDASH')
    system(echo "-F- /abc/site/home/$USER/.userauthentication permission is         set to $permission1")
    exit
    endif

  @ i = 1

 given ($i <= $#argv) 
 switch ($argv[$i])
  when(block):
  return $argv[$i]

 when(tag):
  return $argv[$i]

 when (local):

  return $argv[$i]

 when (ar):
  return $argv[$i]

 default:
  system(echo "-E- Invalid switch -> {$argv[$i]} found!")
  goto usage
  exit
  endsw
 end
```

Comment: The `switch` feature is fine if you enable it. But there are some syntax errors.

Comment: Use [Getopt::Long](http://p3rl.org/Getopt::Long) to process command line arguments.

Comment: Instead of `system 'echo'`, you can just `print` or `say`.

Comment: Really wouldn't build in `ls` and `awk` in there either. `ls` you can probably do with `glob` and `stat`.

Comment: You "Perl Code" lasts right up to the first `if` statement. Then, it's pretty much Perl-ish csh. In Perl we use `{` and `}` for blocks. There is no `endif`. We don't use bare paths, but put them in quotes. (single, double, or quote operator). You also can't use `$USER` in double quotes (interpolative quotes) without defining `$USER` in Perl. You can't even pass it to a `system` call, because it will either be blank (without  `use strict;`), or cause a compile error (with `use strict;`)

Answer (score 1):

Your `given-when` seems to be trying to process command line arguments. It'll work, but it's probably better to use one of the various `GetOpt` modules depending on your need.

[`GetOpt::Long`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) is core, and will do what you want:

```
#/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long;

my %opt; 

my $DBB1; 
my $tag;
my $local; 

GetOptions ( "block=s" => \$DBB1,
             "tag=s" => \$tag,
             "local=s" => \$local ) or die "Invalid option specified";

print $tag,"\n";
```

This allows you to:

```
myscript.pl --tag=fish
myscript.pl --tag fish
myscript.pl -tag fish
```

And sets it into `$tag`. It'll tell you off if you use an invalid opt.

I would also suggest that you're overusing `system` and backticks. You don't need to `system ( "echo ..." );` but can instead `print "Something\n";`. (or use `say` which inserts a linefeed automatically).

Likewise `ls` - it's bad for a couple of reasons. Parsing `ls` is inherently difficult, and has a bunch of edge cases that'll trip you up. You shouldn't do that anyway.

But especially not when you're spawning an `ls` then an `awk` to - as far I can tell - just to get the permissions on a single file. If you need to expand a path, you can use `glob` (but you don't).  And to get what you want, you can use `stat`.

```
my $perms = ( stat "/nfs/site/home/$ENV{'USER'}/.userauthentication" )[2] & 07777;
if ( $perms == 0600 ) { 
    print "Is user-rw, no access to anyone else\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I translated your script for what your script does. I ***do not*** recommend feeding fields to be `chomp`-ed in another perl script. There is probably a better way to do what you want.

The script below doesn't try to find out what you wished `$logFile` was set to. Or try to correct bad processing. It simply shows you a better transformation (not including my style quirks) of what you tried to do with so many system calls, and un-transformed csh.

- [**`-e`**](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)—*with a quoted path*—can check existence.
- [**`die`**](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html) is how you exit with an error.
- [**`File::stat::stat`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::stat) will get you the permissions
- [**`Getopt::Long`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt::Long) will do all your option parsing for you.
- You don't need to shell out for awk, or grep or sed. It's all just the way Perl works:

And here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::stat;
use Getopt::Long;

my $user      = $ENV{USER} // 'USER NOT SET';
my $home_path = "/abc/site/home/$user";
my $auth_path = "$home_path/.userauthentication";
my $machine   = 'c16991';
my $pgMachine = 'lc0140';

# How you error-out in Perl: just die
die ( "-F- .userauthentication file must be created in $home_path\n"
    . "-I- .userauthentication file format: <emailaddress> <unix pwd>.\n"
    . "-I- Please make sure $auth_path permission is set to 000\n  "
    )
    unless -e $auth_path
    ;

# stat does permissions for Perl. 
my $perms = stat( $auth_path )->mode & 0777;

if ( $perms ) { # non zero
    my $permstr = sprintf "%3.3o", $perms;
    die "-F- $auth_path permission is set to: $permstr";
}

# switch processing already baked-in.
GetOptions ( 'block=s' => \$DBB1
           , 'tag=s'   => \$tag
           , 'local=s' => \$local 
           ) 
    or die "Invalid option specified"
    ;

die '-F- Please enter tag value to proceed!'
    if ( $local = 'y' and not $tag )
    ;
# $logFile is undefined in your script.
open ( my $lh, '<', $logFile ) 
    or die "Could not open $logFile!"
    ;
open ( my $out, '>', "/tmp/transpose_$$.pl" ) 
    or die "Could not open transpose_$$ file!"
    ;

# No need for grep or sed.
while ( <$lh> ) { 
    #next unless s/.*Username: //; # grep + sed
    #s/;.*//; # sed 

    # better yet, this does it all:
    next unless my ( $cap ) = m/\bUsername:\s([^;]+)/;

    # Don't do this. 
    # There should be a better way than outputing another perl script.
    say {$out} "chomp $cap;"; 
    # Do you need to quote what you captured?
    # say {$out} "chomp '$cap';";

}
close $lh;
```

Comment: thanks for the comments! @Axeman,  the csh script has many sed, awk, grep, zgrep statements. I didn't understand when you mentioned "no need to sed or grep", which means is there a better to handle that syntax. The script is also creating a perl script to create a new file to push all the csh to  the file, if I that may be right. Is there a better to handle to this ?

Comment: hi what would be the correct syntax for "ls" when porting it to Perl from csh? thanks

Comment: @luxy, if you simply want the base names of a directory, you can use `glob( '*' )`. But I'll refer you here: http://perlmeme.org/faqs/file_io/directory_listing.html and here: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Path::Class and here: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find::Rule